# jQuery add class not working well

Tags: javascript

For some reason my code is not working, because it is not adding a class.

I want to add a class when clicking on the `<a>` and when clicking again it should be removed. When clicking again it should be added and so on.

What am I missing?

HTML:

```
<a class="show-specs" id="displayText" href="javascript:toggle();">Show specs</a>
```

Script:

```
<script language="javascript"> 
function toggle() {
    var ele = document.getElementById("toggleText");
    var text = document.getElementById("displayText");
    if(ele.style.display == "block") {
            ele.style.display = "none";
            .addClass( "left-float" );
        text.innerHTML = "Show specs";
    }
    else {
        ele.style.display = "block";
        text.innerHTML = "Hide specs";
    }
} 
</script>
```

Comment: did you forget `ele` in front of `.addClass ( "left-float" );` ?  ... also ensure that `ele` is not null, and that `ele.style.display` is indeed `block` ...   by the way, I don't see any `jQuery` here, only vanilla JS

Comment: Just `.addClass( "left-float" );` is inncorrect syntax, you need a selector before the dot like `$(...).addClass( "left-float" );`.

Comment: Check [your console for errors.](http://stackoverflow.com/documentation/javascript/185/hello-world/714/using-console-log) It will help you out a lot.

Comment: @Josh `addClass()` is the only jQuery method being used (*incorrectly*).

Comment: That is a somewhat strange toggling, do you intend to remove the class, and why not just do `$('#toggleText').toggle().toggleClass('left-float')` ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to add a [selector](https://api.jquery.com/category/selectors/) before a jQuery method like so:

```
$("#displayText").addClass( "left-float" );
```

The string `"#displayText"` means to select the element with the id `"displayText"`.

Although there is a better way to do this in jQuery by using [`.toggleClass()`](https://api.jquery.com/toggleClass/) such as:

```
$("#displayText").click(function() {
    $(this).toggleClass("left-float");
});
```

[**Demo**](https://jsfiddle.net/gx39g701/)

---

Since you are using jQuery to attach an event handler replace the href with `#`:

```
<a class="show-specs" id="displayText" href="#">Show specs</a>
```

Comment: Thanks for your help and explanation!

Answer (score 1):

Use `ele.className += "left-float";`

```
<script language="javascript"> 
function toggle() {
    var ele = document.getElementById("toggleText");
    var text = document.getElementById("displayText");
    if(ele.style.display == "block") {
            ele.style.display = "none";
            text.className += "left-float";
        text.innerHTML = "Show specs";
    }
    else {
        ele.style.display = "block";
        text.innerHTML = "Hide specs";
    }
} 
</script>
```

Comment: Thanks! I tried that, but it is not adding the class to the `<a>`

Comment: @HenkZ How are we supposed to know that? You never stated what element needs that class.

Comment: @SpencerWieczorek Sorry, you are right. I want to add a class to the `<a>`.

Comment: @HenkZ The `<a>` with the`id="displayText"` or all `<a>`'s?

Comment: @SpencerWieczorek Only the `<a>` with `id="displayText"`.

Answer (score 0):

So as I see it there's 2 issues here. Firstly your code is missing the selector - and the jQuery / $ variable to which jquery is bound - thus you're not actually invoking anything.

The second issue has to do with the fact that you're mixing way too much traditional javascript with jquery - which can lead to confusion in that some stuff will look like its working and other stuff will seem to be failing.

Here's a piece of working code you can use.

```
<!-- Ensure you include jquery -->    
<script language="javascript"> 
function toggle() {
    var ele = $("#toggleText");
    var text = $("#displayText");
    if(ele.is(":visible")) {
        ele.hide();
        text.addClass("left-float");
        text.text("Show specs");
    } else {
        ele.show();
        text.removeClass("left-float");
        text.text("Hide specs");
    }
} 
</script>
<style>
// DEFINE THE CLASS "left-float" HERE
</style>

<a class="show-specs" id="displayText" href="javascript:toggle();">Show specs</a>
```

Hope this helps!